# th:onchange="javascript:showPIIDoc();"

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf.

This is my select statement in thymeleaf

```
<select id="provider" class="form-control" th:onchange="'javascript:showPIIDoc();'">
                                                <option th:value="0" >Select a Service Provider</option>
                                                <option th:each="provider : ${user.providers}"  name="name"  th:value="${provider.id}" th:text="${provider.name}" >[name]</option>
                                            </select>
```

this is my javascript

```
   <script>
function showPIIDoc()
{
    alert('in here');
}
</script>
```

After running on server i cannot see the alert. Please help me.

Comment: Could you post the generated Markup from the browser (i.e. View Source)?

Comment: The showPIIDoc function in the script in head is not present when i view source it. but its there in the editor.

Comment: What about your console in the browser? Open console and then change selection of "provider", what's the output?

Comment: thank you so much!! I cut the script from the head and pasted in the body. Now its working. the page included the head from fragments folder!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about your onchange attribute with the tag, that requires Thymeleaf.

Change it to

```
<select id="provider" class="form-control" onchange="showPIIDoc()">
     <option th:value="0" >Select a Service Provider</option>
     <option th:each="provider : ${user.providers}"  name="name"  th:value="${provider.id}" th:text="${provider.name}" >[name]</option>
</select>
```